# Detect change in page/completion of animation to another page in UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I have the following function which I would like to call whenever the user swipes from one page to another (vertical paging):

```
func sendNotification (){

    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "stopVideo"), object: nil)
    print("called")

}
```

Currently, the function is called whenever the pageAfter or -before is created so to say. The function used to "create" the next/previous page looks like this (in this case it's `viewControllerAfter`):

```
func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

    let currentIndexString  = (viewController as! MyViewController).index
    let currentIndex        = indec.index(of: currentIndexString!)

    //set if so that next page
    if currentIndex! < indec.count - 1 {

        let myViewController = MyViewController()

        myViewController.index            = indec[currentIndex! + 1]

        sendNotification() //function is called 

        return myViewController

    }

    return nil

}
```

Since the UIPageViewController somewhat prepares the following pages and going back to the previous page also doesn't call the function (as the view controller does not need to be "created") I do not get the result I want. I was wondering if there is a function in which I can call `sendNotification()` on completion of the animation. I found a lot of questions regarding jumping to another page but none concerning my problem. I'd really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `UIPageViewControllerDelegate` Functions

```
func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, willTransitionTo pendingViewControllers: [UIViewController])
func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted completed: Bool)
```

As the name of these functions say, the first one will be called, when the user swipes to another page of your PageViewController.

The Second one will be called, when the Transition has completed, which means the user sees the next page after the animation.

In both you can check for changes between the pages.

Also do not forget to check the `completed` variable of the second function. If the user starts swiping and then does not go to the next page (cause he releases the finger before it or similar) it is false and you do not have your new ViewController.

The array `previousViewControllers` holds the recently shown controllers where `previousViewControllers[0]` is probably the one shown before.

For more Information look up the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipageviewcontrollerdelegate)

Comment: I am still learning swift and not completely sure how I would call my function inside... I added to `UIPageViewControllerDelegate` to my class types and tried to simply put my function inside the second function but it doesn't work...

Comment: could you update your Question and show the use of the delegate method?

Comment: Found my mistake, forgot to `delegate = self`... ‍♂️ thank you!

Comment: You need to watch out for the second functions because: while swiping try putting second finger on the screen and keep on swiping. Remove the finger that you put first on the screen and swipe the second one the way not to allow the newly opened page to bounce and debug the function. Even if the actions seems to be finished and completed, completed equals FALSE, I believe that is a gesture interruption error.

Comment: You can save controller id to temporary variable in willTransitionTo and use it in didFinishAnimating when completed is true (occurs when transition is completed)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it will be good for you to run your notification method in `UIPageViewControllerDelegate` method documentation [documentation](https://kapeli.com/dash_share?docset_file=Apple_API_Reference&docset_name=Apple%20API%20Reference&path=dash-apple-api://load?request_key=hsnEy8U0tq&platform=apple&repo=Main&source=https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uipageviewcontrollerdelegate/1614090-pageviewcontroller) :

```
optional func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, 
              didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, 
         previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], 
             transitionCompleted completed: Bool)
```